# Beta version to Production

Tags: android, google-play

I have published a beta version to google play store and now I have made some changes in the app and I want to publish it as production release.

How can I do that? Should I remove the beta version and then publish it again in production? if yes how to remove it?

Comment: Adding your changes. Create a new Prod version for reviewing OR create a new Beta version for reviewing after testing the app carefully -> publish it to Prod

Comment: I think there is no need to remove just update the new version. It will replace your old beta version

Comment: As soon as you push a new version to production, the beta release will be removed

Answer (score 0):

No need to remove beta version.
Just increase version number in gradle file, generate new apk/aap and publish it as production.